# Disable autorotation in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game that uses the accelerometer to move the player. For this reason, I would like to disable autorotation so that the screen will not be accidentally rotated during play. I am pretty new to Cocos2d, and I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Returning NO in the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
```

method in the app's delegate and using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

in the layer works, but then a black rectangle appears on the right 1/3 of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the cocos2d template look for the file *GameConfig.h*, otherwise search for **GAME_AUTOROTATION** and define it to *kGameAutorotationNone*

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
```

Comment: Wow, deceptively simple. Thanks so much.

Comment: It's even simpler in Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) where all of those settings can be found in the config.lua file.